# How do I reclaim memory after parsing via substrings? intern() or new String()?

Tags: java, memory

Short version: If you call string.substring(n,m).intern(), does the string table retain the substring or the original string?

...But I'm not sure that's the right question to ask, so here's the long version:

I'm working with legacy Java code (PCGen) that parses files by slurping each in as one big string and then using String.split, .trim, .substring, and StringTokenizer to decompose them into tokens. This is very efficient for parsing, because none of those methods copy the original string, but all point at parts of a shared char[].

After parsing is over, I want to reclaim some memory. Only a few small substrings of the original big string are needed, but the strong reference keeps the big string from being collected. And later I'm suffering OOM, I believe due in part to that huge heap impact of lots of parsed files.

I know I can trim the big string down via `new String(String)`(copy-on-write). And I know I can reduce string duplication via String.intern (which is important because there's a lot of redundancy in the parsed files). Do I need to use both to reclaim the greatest quantity of heap, or does .intern() do both? Reading the OpenJDK7 hotspot source code (hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/symbolTable.cpp) it looks like the string table keeps the whole string and does not trim it for offset/length at all. So I think I need to make a new String and then intern that result. Right?

All that said, switching to a streaming parser would be a big win in terms of memory, but that's too big a change for the short term.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use new String(String) and the intern() method and this will take a copy as required for up to Java 7 update 4.  From Java 7 update 5 substring will take a deeper copy, but you may still want to use intern().  Note: Java 7 uses the heap, not the perm gen to store String literals.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] chars = new char[128];
    Arrays.fill(chars, 'A');
    String a128 = new String(chars);
    printValueFor("a128", a128);
    String a16 = a128.substring(0, 16);
    printValueFor("a16", a16);
}

public static void printValueFor(String desc, String s) {
    try {
        Field value = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
        value.setAccessible(true);
        char[] valueArr = (char[]) value.get(s);
        System.out.println(desc + ": " + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(valueArr)) + ", len=" + valueArr.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

on Java 7 update 4 prints

```
a128: 513e86ec, len=128
a16: 53281264, len=16
```

I would expect that Java 6 does not do this.

Comment: I'm confused now. Before update 5, `substring` will retain the original backing array. So far, so good. But the `intern()` method documentation says that if no equal string is in the intern pool, the string it's called on will be added to the pool, and `this` is returned. How can that take a copy?

Comment: This is very interesting ... and news to me. Do you have some sources for this?

Comment: Good. I just confirmed that you're right via the hotspot code, because intern() calls java_lang_String::as_unicode_string which copies the characters.

Comment: @JonSkeet - the javadoc is a simplified version of what's actually happening. In reality (at least in the open source jdk7) it always returns a string from the string table and never just `this`

Comment: String is a bit hard to work out.  This is because it doesn't follow it's own code in Java 7 update 4.  The code suggests the underlying `value` array is retained but when you run it, you can see it is not.

Comment: @ChrisDolan: That sounds like it's not just simplified, but verifiably incorrect.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: So it *does* return the reference to the existing string, but it creates a copy of the char array and atomically updates the index/count fields (or whatever they were called then)?

Comment: @JonSkeet: yep, agreed. I suspect the javadoc reflects the 1.0 or 1.1 implementation, perhaps.

Comment: @ChrisDolan: Well I can't test it as I don't have an older version of the JDK to hand - but if you've got a version prior to jdk1.7u5 you should be able to validate it pretty simply.

Comment: Okay, I'm now *really* confused. Your test seems to show it being, copied, but Evgeniy Dorofeev's shows it *not* being copied (i.e. sharing a char array). I don't remember the last time I was quite this confused about Java behaviour.

Comment: @JonSkeet I suspect it is very version specific if you have Java 7.  What makes it extra confusing is that String is heavily optimised by the JVM. e.g. in Java 6 you can enable `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` which is the default on some versions.  This uses a `byte[]` when it can. i.e. it doesn't have to follow the code provided.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Fair enough. I'm going to leave my answer deleted, and try not to say anything definite on this subject ever again ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet Hopefully that will decide on one implementation (I would still like to see compressed strings come back) and documented it appropriately.

Comment: In java 6,output for Evgeniy Dorofeev's test case is true, false:-)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: awesome code example. On jdk1.6 and on Android 4.2, I get `a128: 2c6f7ce9, len=128\n a16: 2c6f7ce9, len=128`. Fascinating.

Comment: So just to check, Peter - your first answer which said that `intern()` would sometimes create a copy... do you still believe that's true, or not? (I'm trying to work out how it could...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: in the code I'm looking at, the as_unicode_string method makes a copy unconditionally. See StringTable::intern() at line 568 of http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/352622fd140a/src/share/vm/classfile/symbolTable.cpp and java_lang_String::as_unicode_string() at line 270 of http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/81d815b05abb/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.cpp

Comment: @JonSkeet: true, I left out the linking step: JVM_InternString() which is at line 3639 of here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp. But I just realized that the URLs I've been posting are to an older branch of jdk7, not the update branch. I didn't notice that before.

Comment: @ChrisDolan: Fundamentally I'd really like to see code *running* on different versions - but I'm not going to start creating VMs just to install old versions of Java ;)

Answer (score 3):

We can test it. String holds its character array in a field

```
   private final char value[];
```

let's see what happens after substring(); intern();

```
    Field f = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    String s1 = "12345";
    String s2 = s1.substring(1, 2);
    String s3 = s2.intern();
    System.out.println(f.get(s2) == f.get(s1));
    System.out.println(f.get(s3) == f.get(s2));
```

output

```
true
true
```

that is, all 3 strings share the same character array

Comment: Very cool, I should have thought of a test like that. What JVM is that? Other answers have suggested that this behavior might have changed in 1.7u5

Comment: Yes, I know about 1.7u5, mine is HotSpot 1.7.0_03